# « Se vassaliser devant/à quelqu'un » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, prépositions, verbes-pronominaux, transitivité

> [...] Ce que veut Mme Le Pen, c'est **se vassaliser devant** monsieur
>   Poutine et devant M. Trump. (Propos de Mme Nathalie Loiseau rapportés
>   ds. [Lapresse.com](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/europe/201905/19/01-5226723-france-lextreme-droite-qualifiee-de-cheval-de-troie-de-poutine-et-trump.php), je souligne)

Le TLFi montre un emploi du verbe transitif [*vassaliser*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vassaliser) en relations internationales « rendre semblable à un [vassal](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vassal), [asservir](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/asservir) ». Je suis un peu surpris par l'emploi de la préposition [*devant*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/devant), je m'attendais plutôt à *à*, un peu sur le modèle l'emploi pronominal [réfléchi](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2954) d'*asservir* ou d'[*inféoder*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/inf%C3%A9oder) (*qqn. s'inféode/s'asservit à qqn.*).

- Peut-on analyser la nature de « devant monsieur Poutine et devant M.
  Trump » et indiquer si c'est un complément indirect ou second du verbe ou
  autrement ; n'y a-t-il aucun lien entre le verbe et ce complément ?
- Pourquoi choisit-on la préposition *devant* plutôt que *à* ; peut-on utiliser *à* ?

  - S'agit-il bien du sens « rendre semblable à un vassal, asservir » ou
    est-ce employé pour signifier autre chose et quoi donc ; tente-t-on de connoter un autre verbe ou une autre locution verbale avec ce choix de préposition et si oui laquelle ?

Comment: Ça ne se dit pas. Loiseau s'est simplement trompée. On dit effectivement "se vassaliser à".

Comment: Ce *devant* ne me choque pas vraiment. Il vient peut-être d'une assimilation avec *s'agenouiller **devant** MM. Poutine et Trump*.

Comment: @jlliagre Ou encore pire,  moi,  je pensais a "prosterner devant."

Comment: Ça évoque pour moi aussi ce genre d'actions. N'hésitez pas à répondre directement, possiblement en déterminant si avec _à_ se dit et si ça veut dire autre chose...

Answer (score 2):

**Devant** ne devrait pas vous inquiéter, n'importe quel autre verbe aurait pu avoir `devant`.

`Être asservi à`  renvoie à une **addiction** ou une soumission

Donc de **vassal** on déduit une forme de dépendance diplomatique ou patriotique, puis **se vassaliser** nous donne "se soumettre devant un chef ou une puissance liée à la diplomatie"

Quant à **Devant** on pourrait aussi dire qu'elle s'est attachée *à un arbre* devant ... Ou avant ... Ou comme ...

On ne se `vassalise` pas `à quelqu'un`  mais `à quelque chose`  ou `devant / dernière / comme / si / ... quelqu'un ...`

Je pense qu'il y'a un peu de figurations dans cette phrase de Mme Nathalie Loiseau

Answer (score 1):

Je trouve que l'expression "se vassaliser devant ..." très inélégante ; il aurait mieux valu dire simplement

Mme L. apparaît comme la vassale docile et empressée de V. Poutine.

Comment: Oui mais, ça n'indique pas que cette "vassalisation" est de son fait, comme la phrase originale.